# What's the meaning of "typedef" in struct

Tags: c

What is the difference between:

```
typedef struct
{

} hello;
```

And:

```
struct hello
{

};
```

Sorry if it is a stupid question but i cannot understand what the difference is...

Comment: With the first one, you can do `hello tmp;` but with the second you have to do `struct hello tmp;`

Answer (score 3):

`typedef` is a keyword meaning "type definition".  It is not part of the struct.  In your first example, it makes `hello` to be a new type which is `struct { ... }`

The first creates a type; the second declares a struct named `hello`.

The difference is that the first creates a new type.  The second only declares a struct.  The difference is subtle, but in `C`, you cannot reuse a struct without the `struct` keyword:   (In C++, the scope rules are different.)

To use the type, write something like this:

```
 typedef struct {
      int x, y;
 } hello;

 hello a, b, c;
```

This creates three variables all of type `hello`.

To use the struct, write this:

```
 struct xyz {
      int  z;
 };

 struct xyz  d, e, f;
```

Comment: The second one does not create a variable; it creates a type named `struct hello`.

Comment: @jwodder:  You are correct.  Maybe it got edited.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: Finally, my edit didn't get lost in the aether.